# React: HashRouter Not Reloading Page on Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-router-dom

Im using HashRouter in my Electron project, however HashRouter does not refresh the navigate page for some reason which is something I need it to do.

Any ideas on how when I click on the route, it would refresh the page?

```
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

```js
  <HashRouter>
    <div>
      <main>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/StatusHub" component={StatusHub} />
        <Route path="/PagerDuty" component={PagerDuty} />
        <Route path="/QuickLinks" component={QuickLinks} />
      </main>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
```

navBar.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

```js
return(
<div>
 <Link to="/">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />
  <span className="label-center">Home</span>
 </Link>

 <Link to="/StatusHub">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFire} />
  <span className="label-center">StatusHub</span>
 </Link>
</div>
)
```

Comment: correct @AjeetShah. I will update my question

Comment: @AjeetShah, it should go to the corresponding component and refresh that component if that makes sense. Similar to how refreshing works in normal web pages when navigating to a different page

Comment: Everything looks correct. You haven't used `Switch`, but it still should work. Can you try with `Switch`? If it doesn't work, I would ask you to create a minimal sandbox if possible.

Comment: @AjeetShah how do I implement Switch?

Comment: @AjeetShah thank you sir! I have implemented Switch and everything is working as expected!

Answer (score 1):

As per help from @Ajeet Shah, I just need `Switch` wrapped around my Routes:

```
  <Router>
    <div>
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/StatusHub" component={StatusHub} />
          <Route path="/PagerDuty" component={PagerDuty} />
          <Route path="/QuickLinks" component={QuickLinks} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
  </Router>
```